# Android build fails because of missing import

Tags: javascript, android, build, expo

I have the following error after `npx expo` using Expo 49 on Android.

```
Android Bundling failed 162ms
Unable to resolve "react-d3-speedometer"
          from "screens/BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.web.tsx"
```

My GitHub project is at:
https://github.com/palenik-martin/bmi-calculator

Here is my `screens/BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.web.tsx`

```js
import ReactSpeedometer, { Transition } from "react-d3-speedometer"
```

However, the `BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.web.tsx` is never supposed to be displayed on Android, which is guaranteed by the following code.

```js
const screenToNavigate = Platform.OS === 'android' ? ScreenName.BMI_RESULT : 
                         Platform.OS === 'web'     ? ScreenName.BMI_RESULT_SPEEDOMETER : 
                         ScreenName.BMI_RESULT; // the default value;
navigation.navigate(screenToNavigate, { bmi: Number.parseInt(bmiResult) });
```

How do I remove it from an Android build to build successfully?

Here is my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "bmi-calculator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "ts:check": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.18",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-d3-speedometer": "github:palerdot/react-d3-speedometer#master",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.6",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.46",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.19.10",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here is my `AppNavigator.tsx`

```js
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import BmiResultScreen from "../screens/BmiResultScreen";
import BmiCalculatorScreen from "../screens/BmiCalculatorScreen";
import { ScreenName } from "../types/ScreenName";
import BmiResultSpeedometerScreen from "../screens/BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.web";

const AppStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = ()=>{
    return(
        <AppStack.Navigator>
            <AppStack.Screen 
                name={ScreenName.BMI_CALCULATOR}
                component={BmiCalculatorScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'BMI CALCULATOR',
                    headerStyle:{
                        backgroundColor: "#0A0C21",
                    },
                    headerTitleStyle:{
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                }}
            />
            <AppStack.Screen 
                name={ScreenName.BMI_RESULT}
                component={BmiResultScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'BMI CALCULATOR',
                    headerStyle:{
                        backgroundColor: "#0A0C21",
                    },
                    headerTitleStyle:{
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                }}
            />
            <AppStack.Screen 
                name={ScreenName.BMI_RESULT_SPEEDOMETER}
                component={BmiResultSpeedometerScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'BMI CALCULATOR',
                    headerStyle:{
                        backgroundColor: "#0A0C21",
                    },
                    headerTitleStyle:{
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                }}
            />
        </AppStack.Navigator>
    )
}

export default AppNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the proper way to solve this? ChatGPT gave me the following answer.

### ChatGPT says:

The issue you're encountering is due to Expo's bundler trying to resolve all imports, regardless of platform-specific conditions in your code. Even though `BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.web.tsx` is not used in the Android build, its import statement is still being processed, leading to the error.

To resolve this, you need to ensure that the bundler does not attempt to process the `BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.web.tsx` file when building for Android. Here are a few strategies you could use:

#### Dynamic Import with Platform Check

Modify your `AppNavigator.tsx` to dynamically import `BmiResultSpeedometerScreen` based on the platform. This way, the problematic module will not be imported at all in the Android build.

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

// Other imports...

let BmiResultSpeedometerScreen;

if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
    BmiResultSpeedometerScreen = require('../screens/BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.web').default;
}

// ...

<AppStack.Screen 
    name={ScreenName.BMI_RESULT_SPEEDOMETER}
    component={BmiResultSpeedometerScreen}
    options={/* ... */}
/>
```

In this setup, `BmiResultSpeedometerScreen` will only be imported if the platform is 'web'. For Android, this component will be `undefined`, and you should handle this case appropriately in your navigator (for example, by not rendering the screen at all).

#### Conditional Screen Registration

Another approach is to conditionally register screens in your navigator based on the platform:

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

// ...

const AppNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <AppStack.Navigator>
            {/* Other screens */}
            {Platform.OS === 'web' && (
                <AppStack.Screen 
                    name={ScreenName.BMI_RESULT_SPEEDOMETER}
                    component={require('../screens/BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.web').default}
                    options={{/* ... */}}
                />
            )}
        </AppStack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

In this approach, the `BmiResultSpeedometerScreen` screen is only added to the navigator if the platform is 'web'. For Android, the screen won't be registered, and thus the problematic module won't be imported.

#### Use Platform-Specific Extensions

You can rename `BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.web.tsx` to `BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.tsx` and create an empty or placeholder component for Android with the name `BmiResultSpeedometerScreen.android.tsx`. This way, React Native's platform-specific file resolution will automatically pick the correct file for each platform.

#### Additional Notes

- Make sure to test your application thoroughly on both platforms to ensure that these changes do not introduce any new issues.
- Since dynamic imports and conditional screen registration can affect your app's navigation flow, you might need to adjust other parts of your code to handle the absence of `BmiResultSpeedometerScreen` on Android.